# Manipulate data in Python

Tags: python, dataset, large-data

I have been working with mathcad for several years but it is not really suitable for data manipulation. I'm learning python and I would like to know how to manipulate data using a python script. Basically my data sets are from a dat file organized as such:

```
w : A_D02
chipX : 6
chipY : -3
ID :2_12-A1
BOD
12  1.93
10  1.5
8   1.43
6   1.46
4   1.39
2   1.41
48  1.35
46  1.41
44  1.39
42  1.44
40  1.44
38  2.08
36  2.1
34  1.47
32  1.46
30  1.42
28  1.45
26  1.37
24  1.41
22  1.39
20  1.44
18  1.46
16  1.49
14  1.97
0   0
EOD
w : A_D02
chipX : 6
chipY : -3
ID : 0.04_10
f : 100000 H
BOD
1.5 -8.48417e-12    0.000105852
1.45    -7.57959e-12    0.000104342
1.4 -6.66443e-12    0.000102611
1.35    -6.66912e-12    0.000101964
EOD
w : A_D02
chipX : 6
chipY : -3
ID : 0.04_10
f : 10000 H
BOD
1.5 2.54351e-12 0.000102326
1.45    3.30898e-12 0.000100371
1.4 4.05372e-12 9.91379e-05
1.35    4.89822e-12 9.86476e-05
EOD
w : A_D02
chipX : 6
chipY : -3
ID : 0.04_10
f : 1e+06 H
BOD
1.5 2.99854e-12 0.000109691
1.45    3.24767e-12 0.000109494
1.4 3.53048e-12 0.000110429
1.35    3.87087e-12 0.000112401
EOD
```

As an output file saved in txt format, I look for doing something like this:

```
w   chipX   chipY   ID  f   V   C   G
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    100000  1.5 -8.48E-12   0.000105852
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    100000  1.45    -7.58E-12   0.000104342
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    100000  1.4 -6.66E-12   0.000102611
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    100000  1.35    -6.67E-12   0.000101964
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    10000   1.5 2.54E-12    0.000102326
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    10000   1.45    3.31E-12    0.000100371
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    10000   1.4 4.05E-12    9.91E-05
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    10000   1.35    4.90E-12    9.86E-05
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    1.00E+06    1.5 3.00E-12    0.000109691
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    1.00E+06    1.45    3.25E-12    0.000109494
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    1.00E+06    1.4 3.53E-12    0.000110429
A_D02   6   -3   0.04_10    1.00E+06    1.35    3.87E-12    0.000112401
EOD
```

I would really appreciate your help because peforming this in excel is really painful especially because I have do it for a large data set ;-(

Comment: I don't understand `BOD` and `EOD` the convert rule, can you explain it?

Comment: BOD is kind of end of the device definition (HEADER)

Comment: EOD is kind of end of the measurement (DATA SET) => only numbers

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend Ipython + Pandas.

Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org) is essentially the excel of python. You can store tabular data in a way that is easy to manipulate and import/export and integrates with many python packages like numpy and scipy. Because it works with these frameworks it also allows for easier bridging to other languages.

Ipython(http://ipython.org/index.html) will give you a great interface for data visualization and allow you to create notebooks to store your work, and work with others.

You may want to check out https://www.enthought.com/canopy-express for quick set up of these tools. Here is a list of the  packages in enthought: https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/

This is also a great book that will walk you through setting up and using these tools:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do

If you are doing this kind of work in python, these are absolutely tools you should know about.

Comment: Interesting tool but mixing txt and data is not easy to handle. I should take a week off to be able to succeed after reading all the python books;-)